# stripe shader no uv unwrapping

Tags: texturing, shaders

I need a shader that achieves the effect in this image, stripes of different colors. This image was produced by uv unwrapping but that would be difficult to achieve on a very complex object. The idea is that the object is made of a material of colored layers and is then carved to give this effect. The image is in ortographic projection. The orientation of the stripes should be a parameter.

Thanks for your help.

[image: goal image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]One way to get stripes is to use a 'Checker Texture' and use a 'Mapping' node to stretch the texture in one axis. Of course this would only produce a two-color striped texture and it appears that you want a multi-colored texture. In that case I think you could layer some 'Checker Textures' using Alpha and offsetting their mapping coordinates. I'll give it a try to see if it's a viable solution and let you know how it goes.

This seems to work (if I understand your question correctly). You would have to play with the values to achieve the thin black line.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. Is that a flat surface in the image you posted?  I guess I don't understand if you mean that the stripes themselves are "carved" or the cylindrical distortion is "carved".